# Escape 5 or 6 hex digit Unicode codepoint

Tags: elixir

In the [Elixir documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/main/String.html#module-escape-characters) it says that you can use the following escapes:

- `\xNN` - A byte represented by the hexadecimal `NN`
- `\uNNNN` - A Unicode code point represented by `NNNN`

So what if I want to escape a codepoint that's longer than 4 hex digits, i.e. is outside the Basic Multilingual Plane, like  `U+1f692 FIRE ENGINE` or all the Private Use characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one syntax that is not described on that page:

```
"\u{1f692}"
```

Comment: Thanks, I submitted a PR https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/pull/12295

Comment: Also: `<<240, 159, 154, 146>>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a binary: `<<0x1f692::utf8>>`

```elixir
iex> cp = 0x1f692
iex> "Nee #{<<cp::utf8>>} naw"
"Nee  naw"
```

Or put it in a charlist `[0x1f692]`:

```elixir
iex> "Nee #{[cp]} naw"
"Nee  naw"
```

Both of these are useful if you have the codepoint in a variable.